# Installing Hybrid Agent fails with "Setup terminiated with an Exit Code 1603"

Tags: exchange-server, hybrid

Trying to run Hybrid Configuration Wizard (HCW) - the part where it says "Installing Hybrid Agent", fails with error code 1603 ("Setup terminiated with an Exit Code 1603").

It seems like an installation issue since it appears to be MSI log that has the error in it (see image).

I imagine this could be TLS issue but I ran nartac tool with best practices AND also unchecked tls 1.0 and 1.1 manually.  Not sure what to do now.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For HCW to work properly with TLS 1.2, verify the SChannel and .NET Framework registry values are enabled.

Create a .REG file, copy the entire section below, then merge the file to update your entries.

---

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
> "SystemDefaultTlsVersions" = dword:00000001
> "SchUseStrongCrypto" = dword:00000001
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
> "SystemDefaultTlsVersions" = dword:00000001
> "SchUseStrongCrypto" = dword:00000001
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
> "SystemDefaultTlsVersions" = dword:00000001
> "SchUseStrongCrypto" = dword:00000001
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
> "SystemDefaultTlsVersions" = dword:00000001
> "SchUseStrongCrypto" = dword:00000001
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS
> 1.2]
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS
> 1.2\Client]
> "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
> "Enabled"=dword:00000001
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS
> 1.2\Server]
> "DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
> "Enabled"=dword:00000001

Answer (score 1):

The answer is correct that the issue is caused by TLS settings, but the REG file isn't complete or at least didn't fix the issue for me.
I found a different [post](https://adminkb.com/hybrid-agent-exit-code-1603/) that had a longer REG file that allowed me to continue my installation.

Here's the longer REG file for reference

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
"Enabled"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
"Enabled"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct key names is "...\Microsoft\.NETFramework..." :-)

Comment: While your answer appears correct, you should provide more detailed information and revise the existing answer with your solution to create the new answer. If you don’t want to take the time to do that then this should be a comment on the accepted answer.